# Loop over json array items

Tags: c++, json, nlohmann-json

I have a C++ code with an `nlohmann::json` array-type object. So it kinda looks like

`[{"abc":-0.09275999665260315,"def":-0.06765999644994736,"ghi":0.0010000000474974513},{"abc":-0.0027000000700354576,"def":0.014310000464320183,"ghi":1.5950000286102295}, ...]`

Now, I want to loop over these elements. What I have done is basically follow what is written here: https://json.nlohmann.me/api/basic_json/items/, but it does not really seem to work.
My code is (with the json object being called `lines`):

```
std::cout << lines.dump() << std::endl;
std::cout << "size is: "<< lines.size() << std::endl;
for(auto& elm : lines.items()){
    ++nLines;
    nlohmann::json line = elm.value();
    std::cout << elm << std::endl;
    std::cout << "line: " << line.dump() << std::endl;
    ...
}
```

and my output is (truncating after first loop since downstream code crashes):

```
[{"abc":-0.09275999665260315,"def":-0.06765999644994736,"ghi":0.0010000000474974513},{"abc":-0.0027000000700354576,"def":0.014310000464320183,"ghi":1.5950000286102295}, ...]
size is: 638
{"0":null}
line: null
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance!

conni

Answer (score 0):

OK I found a problem with my original json file. The iteration itself is fine. Apologies for wasting everybody's time.